# wearing necklaces that have verses from the Quran on them a sin?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, shirk

I don't understand how this is a form of Shirk?
I'm not Questioning Allah but no body has given me anything from the Quran that says we cannot wear necklaces with Quranic verses in them can somebody please explain how this would be shirk???
I mean it is Allahs words in the necklace to begin with?
Please don't be rude in your answers I'm genuinely unsure about this and would like to know more about this topic

Comment: So called (fake) sheikhs give people amulets which contain Quranic verses to 'protect them' with names of Shaytan and is therefore shirk.

Comment: What if one was to make the amulet he selected?

Comment: Please provide links to support your question. Which fatwas say what types of necklaces with verses of the Qur'an are shirk? Without reading the fatwas, this will be a matter of speculation.

Answer (score 4):

There is no clear cut on the issue of written verses of qur'an on objects of daily use. But there's a consensus that once these verse would be misused or misplaced it is at least makrooh (frowned upon).

For example writing Qur'an verses on walls, clothes, food is makrooh ...  but it is permitted to destroy a wall with such verses on it or wear clothes where there are written on this based on a statement in [Zakaria al-Ansari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zakariyya_al-Ansari)'s book asna al-Matalib his commentary on the fiqh book rawd at-Tulaab أسنى المطالب في شرح روض الطالب which was quoted in [this Arabic fatwa](http://www.awqaf.gov.ae/Fatwa.aspx?SectionID=9&RefID=3338) asking whether it is permissible to buy or sell clothes on which qur'an verses or the name(s) of Allah are printed on. This is basically there considered as permitted unless these clothes are used in a disrespectful way for the written text.

So basically all scholars agree that once you misuse such clothes or a neckless by for example entering a toilet wearing them it becomes at least makrooh if not haram. This is also the opinion presented in this Arabic fatwa on [islamweb #51490](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/51490). The opinion is based on the fact that the Prophet had a ring on which was written "Muhammad Rasull Allah" (Sahih [al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/77/94) and sahih [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/37/93)). And he used to take it off when entering the "toilet":

> "When the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) entered the area in which he would relieve himself, he would remove the ring." (Jami' [at-Tirmdihi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/24/27), sunan [abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/1/19), sunan [ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1303210), sunan [an-Nasa'i](https://sunnah.com/nasai/48/174))

See also this fatwa on [islamqa #68805](https://islamqa.info/en/68805) allowing printing or writing the name of Allah on rings.
So far shirk is excluded.

The issue of shirk only arise if you wear such a verse **believing** it may protect you from any bad or as a talisman or amulet. As shirk is related to what you believe an object a being or deity except Allah may do for you.

> I heard Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) saying, "The reward of deeds depends upon the intentions and every person will get the reward according to what he has intended. So whoever emigrated for worldly benefits or for a woman to marry, his emigration was for what he emigrated for (Sahih [al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/1/1) and other ahadith collections)

This fatwa on [islamqa #91370](https://islamqa.info/en/91370) seems to declare all these things as haram for two major reasons:

1. disrespect
2. imitation of disbelievers.

According to that one is sinning when selling it, when buying it and when wearing it.

This fatwa also includes two ahadith from Musnad Ahmad saying which seem to be used in the context of wearing these verses such as if wearing an amulet, which indeed is a matter of shirk:

> Ahmad (17458) narrated from ‘Uqbah ibn ‘Aamir al-Juhani (may Allaah be pleased with him) that the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever wears an amulet has associated something with Allaah (shirk).” Classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Jaami’.
>
> Ahmad also narrated (17440) that ‘Uqbah ibn ‘Aamir (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: I heard the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) say: “Whoever wears an amulet, may Allaah not fulfil his need, and whoever wears a sea-shell, may Allaah not give him peace.” Classed as hasan by Shu’ayb al-Arna’oot in Tahqeeq al-Musnad.

Finally note that scholars like al-Qurtobi in his tafsir discussed the matter on writing on ornaments or rings while commenting or interpreting verse ([16:14](http://legacy.quran.com/16/14)):

> And it is He who subjected the sea for you to eat from it tender meat and **to extract from it ornaments which you wear**. And you see the ships plowing through it, and [He subjected it] that you may seek of His bounty; and perhaps you will be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

*If it is not in the Qur'an, it is not shirk.*

يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا لَا تُحَرِّمُوا طَيِّبَاتِ مَا أَحَلَّ اللَّهُ لَكُمْ وَلَا تَعْتَدُوا ۚ إِنَّ اللَّهَ لَا يُحِبُّ الْمُعْتَدِينَ - 5:87

**'"O you who have believed, do not prohibit the good things which Allah has made lawful to you and do not transgress. Indeed, Allah does not like transgressors.""**

وَلَا تَقُولُوا لِمَا تَصِفُ أَلْسِنَتُكُمُ الْكَذِبَ هَٰذَا حَلَالٌ وَهَٰذَا حَرَامٌ لِّتَفْتَرُوا عَلَى اللَّهِ الْكَذِبَ ۚ إِنَّ الَّذِينَ يَفْتَرُونَ عَلَى اللَّهِ الْكَذِبَ لَا يُفْلِحُونَ - 16:116

**"And do not say about what your tongues assert of untruth, "This is lawful and this is unlawful," to invent falsehood about Allah . Indeed, those who invent falsehood about Allah will not succeed."**

Don't let the Human opinion influence you. I have one myself with Ayat  Al-kursi on it and I absolutely love wearing it. I feel very protected when I have it on.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Assalam O Alaikum Brother!

(May Allah (SWT) have mercy on all of us)

I'm in distress time and is seeking refuge from Allah (SWT). He is the mighty and knows all.

Sorry but this is not an answer but I'm also looking for the answer. May Allah (SWT) guide us in right path.

I searched the internet and almost 80% on my research lead to that it is haram. But I'm confused how it is haram if we keep a Quranic verse in a form on an amulet.

I'm a human being and at least have this much common sense to understand that wearing stones, bones, shells and believing on them is shirk. But if we use a Quranic verse and still believe that will help us then I don't think my intention will be wrong?

I upvote the two answers above me because my heart says it seems right.

also wanted to share this article which has some reference regarding this question.

[Islamic Beliefs & Teachings](http://islamicbeliefsandteachings.blogspot.com/2014/11/taweez-amulets-in-light-of-quran-sunnah.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assalaam Alaiqum wa Rehmat Allah.
In my personal opinion, it is all dependent upon one's intention.  Having an intention that wearing such and such will protect us, would ultimately bring us to a compromised state.  That itself is a sign of weaker faith because protector is One and Only Allah Almighty. Nothing can harm us except by his permission, Remember this very base factor and it shall solve your basic concern and unfound fears. Shetan gives fears, it is True faith which provides hope and good tidings.
Everything happens by permission of Allah.
 قُل لَّن يُصِيبَنَآ إِلَّا مَا كَتَبَ ٱللَّهُ لَنَا هُوَ مَوْلَىٰنَا ۚ وَعَلَى ٱللَّهِ فَلْيَتَوَكَّلِ ٱلْمُؤْمِنُونَ
Al tauba 51...

Remember nothing can befalls upon us except that which is written for us. That which is meant to happen, will happen even if we wear Entire Qur'an upon us or even if we quarantine ourselves in a closed glass cube. Period!
Now on an another note, if we just wear it because it is a better choice to wear it rather than some worldly oriented sculpted pattern, it will remain to be the better chooce.

However, the next responsibility comes upon us would then be to ensure that no disrespect happens to it's sacredness.  Rest Assured Allah knows best. May Allah keep us guided to straight path Aameen. بألف الصلاة والسلام على نبينا محمد صلى الله عليه وسلم وعلى آله وأصحابه أجمعين

Answer (score -2):

I had a SILVER PLATED CHAIN WITH ALLAHS NAME. THE REASON I WEAR IT? CAUSE IT REMINDS ME THAT ALLAH IS WITH ME AND WATCHING OVER ME. AND TO BE WELL AWARE OF MY ACTIONS,TO THINK BEFORE ACTING. ITS JUST LIKE HAVING A QURAN TO REMEMBER AND READ. JUST LIKE WE HAVE THE AHDEN CALLING ON ARE CELLPHONES TO BE REMINDED of the salat so dont you want to BE aware of the most high so carry ALLAH'S name and attribute at heart with good intentions whenever we leave we dont go back until he brightens our hearts remember that. So remember him in anyway but with a open heart.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).